# An image inserted in a spreadsheet with a script is not printed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I manually add the (Google Drive) image to the spreadsheet it is printed.

When I add the same image by using the script

```
source.insertImage("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B5actcstcwPhZG0zVzQ2WG1DMVk", 1, 1);
```

then the image is on the right place, and looks the same,  but it is not printed.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if `insertImage` [wants a URL pointing to an image, not a Drive file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertimageurl-column-row).

I would suggest getting the image as a Blob by using `DriveApp.getFileById('0B5actcstcwPhZG0zVzQ2WG1DMVk')` and see if that works.

Comment: You can `insertImage(blob, column, row)` from [insertImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertcolumnsbeforebeforeposition-howmany) then add the blob from the `getBlob()` from [Drive File Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#methods)